# AHK script when screen projected to connected screen

Tags: display, script, autohotkey

How to create a AHK script where depending on the screen situation (ie, if it is projected onto another screen or not) an application is open at a certain area or at another area

Answer (score 0):

If the screen is 'projected onto another screen', are you referring to a computer plugged into a projector?  If so, does the monitor resolution change to match the resolution of the projector?  Projector resolutions are typically different than a computer monitor or laptop screen, and if the resolution changes for a projector, then the different resolution settings can be detected and discriminated on using `SysGet`.

If a projector is just mirroring the monitor you may not be able to detect a resolution difference using that method.

Once you know whether the projector is active, you can open and/or detect a program and move it to a certain area of the screen using `Run`, and/or `WinActivate`, `WinWaitActive` and `WinMove`

Comment: yes, I mean that my computer is plugged into the projector, and my computer monitor resolution changes, and I want to do something special in AHK

Comment: Well then that shouldn't be a problem and my suggestions above would stand... you can poll the resolution to see if it changes (when a projector is plugged in) and then launch and/or move windows around when it does.